# go install - different behavior on Win10 than osx or linux

Tags: go

I have GOPATH set to:

```
~/Projects/golang
```

On Linux, OSX and Win10. My code is under:

```
$GOPATH/src/bitbucket.org/user/project/sublib
```

with pkg in the appropriate parallel loacation. On Linux and OSX I can run go install in the sublib directory and the lib builds and gets installed in

```
$GOPATH/pkg/bitbucket.org/user/project/sublib.a
```

and everything imports fine. On Windows 10 however with the same rig, I need to supply the path when installing:

```
> go install bitbucket.org\user\project\sublib
```

which works, but the imports in main() (say) do not.

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "bitbucket.org/user/project/sublib"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
```

does not compile. What am I missing on Windows?

```
John@RATBONE C:\Users\John\Projects\golang\src\bitbucket.org\user\project\sublib> go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=C:\Users\john\Projects\golang\bin
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\john\Projects\golang
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
> go version
go version go1.9.2 windows/amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: case error in GOPATH (john vs. John). Never noticed it. Odd that it affected go install but not go build of main()?